# How do I resolve a glpyh not showing or BAD_COLUMN_NAME error with bokeh when importing my own excel or csv data?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm getting an error trying to plot different excel and csv data with bokeh.

The examples in the tutorial work, but not when I am making my own dataframes with `read_csv` or `read_excel` in pandas.  The error says

> `(BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name:`

Sometimes I just get a blank styled figure object with no plots instead of the error message.  My column names are correct having copy pasted them from the `os.listdir()` output.  However, bokeh is saying the data frame doesn't have these columns, therefore cannot plot them.

My code is below:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook,show 
from bokeh.plotting import figure 
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource 
import pandas as pd 
import os 

output_notebook() 
df = pd.read_csv('weightData.csv') 
source = ColumnDataSource(df) 
p = figure(width=400,height=350) 
p.circle('Weight','Fat mass',size=10, color='orange', 
         x_range_name='Weight', y_range_name='Fat Mass', 
         fill_alpha=0.3) 
show(p)
```

Here's a screenshot of the error I'm getting:
[image: Error]

Comment: from bokeh.io import output_notebook,show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd
import os
os.listdir()
output_notebook()

df = pd.read_csv('weightData.csv')
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(width=400,height=350)
p.circle('Weight','Fat mass',size=10,color='orange',
        x_range_name='Weight',y_range_name='Fat Mass',
        fill_alpha=0.3)
show(p)

Comment: Please edit the code into the question as *text*, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the ***`source`*** to `p.circle(...)` You need to pass `source=source` as an argument. Unless you pass it a source then `p.circle` will just create and use a default (empty) one.

Comment: ...and also `source` has to be a bokeh `DataSource` e.g. `ColumnDataSource`. It can't be a pandas dataframe, dict etc.

Comment: @smci that is not true -- Bokeh has accepted Pandas DataFrames as the `source` argument for many releases.

Comment: You mean I don't need to do `source = ColumnDataSource(ColumnDataSource.from_df(my_df))`? Also, I didn't notice your name at first, is that your [tutorial on hextiles](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)...? I'm currently being thrown by bokeh insisting the y-axis goes down from TL, and forces the axes to be automatic, and insists the labels on the y-axis must be negative... can't figure out how to override that.

Comment: I mean you can do `p.circle(...source=df)` but you can also do `ColumnDataSource(data=df)` This has been possible for at least a few years.  A comment is not the right place for questions. I would encourage the Project Discourse over SO: https://discourse.bokeh.org/

Comment: From the doc and code examples currently floating around, it is not clear you can directly pass a df, without going through the classmethod `ColumnDataSource.from_df`. Anyway my point was `source` cannot be an arbitrary Python dict, list-of-dict, numpy array etc.

Comment: Issues/PRs always welcome! Tho also please see: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#pandas FYI that is not my tutorial, I am the project lead for Bokeh I don't know who wrote that tutorial.

Comment: I believe you're wrong, in Bokeh 1.4.0 I still get `ValueError: 'source' argument to add_glyph() must be DataSource subclass` when I directly to add a df as source in `p.add_glyph(my_df, glyph)`. Anyway that issue is trivial, solution is just use the classmethod. But yeah there are plenty other issues, I'll peruse [discourse.bokeh.org](https://discourse.bokeh.org/) I know that comment are not for raising new questions. But I found so many issues with Bokeh yesterday I had to hack/workaround, I'm trying to triage my most-important ones to ask... I'm not gonna post a laundry-list.

Comment: Respectfully, I am not. :) The question is about glyph methods, e.g. `p.circle(...)` not about the low level `bokeh.models` API, and my answer is accordingly only about that. Not only can DataFrames be passed directly to glyph methods and CDS initializers, but even GroupBy objects as well. All of this is in the User's Guide. Low level APIs are naturally more verbose, and that is true of the low level `add_glyph` function.

Comment: But you claimed the much broader "Bokeh has accepted Pandas DataFrames as the source argument for many releases". Not just p.circle. Not just "a few higher-level parts of the Bokeh API accept..." Consider how confusing it is to new Bokeh users... API overload.

Comment: I literally said this: " you can do p.circle(...source=df) but you can also do ColumnDataSource(data=df)" I did not say *anything* about `add_glyph`, at all. The higher level `bokeh.plotting` API is the majority: User guide, gallery examples, and tutorial notebooks. It's not "a few parts", it's what we alwasy advise people to start with (on the project docs, the thing we actually have control over). More importantly: it is the topic of *this question*. This is not really a productive discussion. If you have further technical questions, I am happy to engage with you on the Project Discours